# SQL - How to find all the same value column

Tags: sql, sql-server

if i have such table

```
    Value1      Value2    
      1            A     
      1            B     
      2            A      
      2            B      
      2            C      
      3            A       
      3            B
      4            A
      4            C
      5            B 
      5            A 
      6            C  
      7            B  
      8            B 
      9            A
```

I want return only the Value1 that have same Value2 (but not more and not left). The result for example must have:

```
   Value1         Result
     1              3,5
     2             NULL
     3              1,5
     4             NULL
     5              1,3
     6             NULL
     7              8
     8              7
     9             NULL
```

I tried with some FUNCTION using DISTINCT and INNER JOIN but i couldn't find any solution. Can someone help me to understand how to do?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: What you mean by "only the Value1 that have same Value2"?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far? And clarify what RDBMS you have, this will determine the best answer.

Comment: I use sql-server

Comment: I mean that I want to know if exist some Value1 that have the same number and type of Value2, sorry if i can't explain better, i tried to do with example...

Comment: what you have tried pls show us

Comment: what is  the value2? (3,5)

Comment: I don't get behind logic, why `Value1 = 1` corresponds `3,5` from `Value2` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Me too , and Value2 column contain chars.

Comment: Value1:1 have the same Value2(A and B) of Value1:3 and Value1:5

Comment: That's completely unclear.

Comment: I got it, but its unclear problem for others

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar You got it? Post your answer

Comment: @Sami - Now I got it also, 1,3,5 all have "A" and "B" values. 2 also, but it also have "C", so this (2) not corresponds to these numbers.  Vladmyr - Is this correct ?

Comment: @Oto Shavadze, yes it is.
 It must have the same Value2. For example:
   1 is equal to 3 and 5 but not to others cause it mustn't have more values (+ "C") or left values (only "A" or only "B")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach with `STUFF`. You could combine `Value2` of each `value1` and compare them.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Value1 int,
    Value2 varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
(1, 'A'),    
(1, 'B'),    
(2, 'A'),     
(2, 'B'),     
(2, 'C'),     
(3, 'A'),      
(3, 'B'),
(4, 'A'),
(4, 'C'),
(5, 'B'),
(5, 'A'),
(6, 'C'), 
(7, 'B'), 
(8, 'B'),
(9, 'A')

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT sd.Value1, 
         stuff((    SELECT ','+ sd2.Value2
                FROM @SampleData sd2
                WHERE sd2.Value1 = sd.Value1    
                ORDER BY sd2.Value2 -- Value2 must be ordered to compare exactly.
                FOR XML PATH('')
              )
                   ,1,1,'') as Value2 
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT sd.Value1
       FROM @SampleData sd
    ) sd
)
SELECT t.Value1, STUFF((
                       SELECT ',' + CAST(t2.Value1 AS varchar(10))
                       FROM temp t2
                       WHERE     t2.Value2 = t.Value2 
                             AND t2.Value1 != t.Value1
                       ORDER BY t2.Value1                       
                       FOR XML PATH ('')
                    )
                    ,1,1,'') as Value2
FROM temp t
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/CMUHA74596

Comment: you are the best. Really thank you, is easy to understand and it work perfectly.

Comment: Happy to help @Vladmyr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a where clause in your sql statement to specify, that only the rows, which have an equal value of Value1 and Value2, are selected.

Use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Value1 FROM table WHERE Value1 = Value2
```

Comment: Sorry is not what i meant, I will change the example

Answer (score 0):

I won't write it for you, but this may guide you towards a solution.

You need to write a function using a FULL OUTER JOIN.  Join the table to itself on `Value1<>Value1` to compare the `Value1` you are testing to all the others.   For each Value1 pairing, when either side of the FULL OUTER JOIN is NULL, then you don't have a match.  When there are no NULLS on either side of the JOIN for a pairing, then they match exactly.